# Combinatorics and Catalan Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, catalan-numbers, young-tableaux

I was asked to investigate this question and to present my findings and I would like some sense of help and direction, I am very lost:-(

1. 2n people, all of different heights
2. How many ways are there to order them such that

   --- There are exactly 2 rows
   --- All the heights increase from left to right
   --- The people in the back row have to be taller than the person immediately in front of them in the first row

Does anyone know of a recurrence relation that there is for this question, or any explicit formulas that I can investigate?

I have worked it for 2n = 6, and have found that in terms of Young Tableaux if we use the equation $\frac{(2n)!}{\prod(Hook's Numbers)}$ we achieve the answer 5, which is also what I got when doing it by hand.

Now I am wondering as to how I would prove this

Comment: The usual first step would be to work it out by hand for the first few small $n$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Try something, at least (as lulu sugests) the small values of $n$, and edit your question to include your work. If you don't show some effort your question will be probably be closed.

Comment: I've assigned an equivalent problem in class in the past. The idea is to construct a bijection between tableaux of type (n,n) and some other set of objects that is counted by the Catalan numbers.  (I don't think the hook formula will be enormously helpful.)

Comment: HINT: Take a look at [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula#Examples).

Comment: I think your question is covered by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1975085/intuition-behind-hook-length-formula